# Flash hangs javascript setTimeout call in IE

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, settimeout

I am calling a Javascript (JS) function from Flash to load some data and show a Flash loading animation while the data loads.

The JS function:

```
getLMSObjectivesStatus()
```

takes some time to complete (e.g. > 30 seconds) due to AJAX calls. As expected, if I call the JS function directly, Flash hangs as it waits for a reply.

To get round this, I've decoupled Flash from Javascript by calling a different JS function from Flash which calls the original JS function using an anonymous function within a setTimeout:

```
function delayedCallToGetObjectives(){
    setTimeout(function(){getLMSObjectivesStatus()},200);
}
```

This works great with Firefox/Chrome as it allows Flash to continue the loading animation without waiting for a response from JS. When the slow JS function has finished, it calls Flash to tell it to use the retrieved data and continue. Lovely, jubbly!

IE doesn't decouple Flash from JS when I use setTimeout. Flash hangs while waiting for both:

```
delayedCallToGetObjectives()
```

and

```
getLMSObjectivesStatus()
```

to complete. I've checked by logging progress and the order tells me this is definitely what is happening.

Does anyone know why this is in IE and are there any fixes/workarounds please?

Comment: Is your Actionscript (Flash) expecting a return value from the JS function it calls?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. No, it's not expecting a return. Flash just calls a function that creates a setTimeout call and does not return anything. JS completes looping through the long function, creating a single string. JS then calls Flash to say it is done and Flash retrieves the data string. Looking for a return caused the initial problem I outlined and worked around with setTimeout. Hope that makes things clearer?

Comment: Yep, perfectly clear thanks. Unfortunately I don't know the answer! :) My first guess is that some of your JS is failing in IE only, possibly due to ECMAScript 5 syntax vs. ECMAScript 3?

Comment: Ach dammit, I thought you were onto something ;-) I'm getting no errors in (IE safe) console but I hadn't looked into ESv5 vs v3 so I'll look into that and post if it gets me anywhere. Thanks anyway!